# robotoframework selenium calculate yesterday date in python script

Tags: robotframework

I have

```
${date}=    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y-%m-%d
```

but I need yesterday date... how can I calculate -1day? I try format %d-1 but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime library has an `Add Time To Date` keyword which should do what you need:

```
${CurrentDate}=  Get Current Date  result_format=%Y-%m-%d

${newdatetime} =  Add Time To Date  ${CurrentDate}  -1 days
```